# Cakephp 3 pagination with 'contain' and 'condition' not working

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have a Device Table containing different ids from different tables e.g. Location, Operators etc.

now I want only some of them shown in my view. so there is an array device_ids with the corresponding ids I want to Show.

I tried

```
$this->paginate['contain'] = ['Locations', 'Operators'];
```

and this shows me all devices with all corresponding Data.

I tried

```
$this->paginate['conditions'] = ['id IN' => $device_ids];
```

and this Shows me only the devices I want to view, but without corresponding Data.

as soon as I Combine those two in

```
$this->paginate[] = [
     'conditions' => ['id IN' => $device_ids],
     'contain' => ['Locations', 'Operators']
];
```

I receive a

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in IN/ALL/ANY subquery is ambiguous.
```

Has anyone has an Explanation for this behaviour? 
What could I change to make this work.

Thanks a lot

L.

Answer (score 0):

sorry,

as soon as I posted the question the answer was there...

I needed to specify the id more, 
so with

```
$this->paginate[] = [
 'conditions' => ['Devices.id IN' => $device_ids],
 'contain' => ['Locations', 'Operators']];
```

it works fine.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You should add model name with field like `ModelName.id`

```
$this->paginate['conditions'] = ['ModelName.id IN' => $device_ids];
```